# Password requirement not same as email regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have an mvc application with this code:

```
public class Register
{
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{7,14}$", ErrorMessage = "Password is not in      proper format")]
public string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

What it does is validate the password to contain atleast 7-14 characters, atleast 1 number and 1 upper case letter.

Another requirement is it should not be the same as the email address.

How can I do that? It seems `[Compare(Email)]` would not be possible on this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Why you don't simply compare password with the e-mail?

Comment: @m0skit0 sorry for the confusion. I am thinking if I can do it with regex.

Comment: @Gerald you don't need regex to do this, see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MVC Foolproof Validation you can write

```
[NotEqualTo("EmailAddress", ErrorMessage="Passwords must be different that EmailAddress")]
public string Password{ get; set; }
```

http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a good idea. However, what is the difference between `NotEqualTo` on `Compare`?

Comment: @Gerald not sure what do you mean. NotEqualTo returns ErrorMessage when Password and Email are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way: create your own attribute which inherits CompareAttribute, and override `IsValid` method. The full code will be like following:

```
    public class NotEqualTo: CompareAttribute
    {
        public NotEqualTo(string otherProperty) : base(otherProperty)
        {
        }
        protected override System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                                                                          System.ComponentModel.
                                                                                              DataAnnotations.
                                                                                              ValidationContext
                                                                                              validationContext)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.OtherProperty);
            if (property == (PropertyInfo) null)
            {
                return
                    new ValidationResult(string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                       "Property {0} does not exist", new object[1]
                                                           {
                                                               (object) this.OtherProperty
                                                           }));
            }
            else
            {
                object objB = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, (object[]) null);
                if (object.Equals(value, objB))
                    return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                else
                    return (ValidationResult) null;
            }
        }
    }
```